# .Net web services transaction

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, transactions

Is there any way transactions can be implemented in .Net web services ?. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF support a rich transactional model - see the

- [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730266.aspx)
- [DevX article](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/30030)
- [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFTransactions.aspx)

on the topic to get up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on hall you define transaction.

Web Services should be made stateless, that is, it should not rely on the client state to perform an operation, so every information the service requires should be send in a single package.

With this in mind, if you define a transaction as a series of requests that ends up with a final "COMMIT" request, then you need to code your service to handle this "transaction", on your own.